# How to solve this homogenous linear equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $$x^2\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}+\frac{dv}{dx}(6x-4)=0$$

So far I have let $$z=\frac{dv}{dx}$$

$$x^2z'+(6x-4)z=0$$

Is this a first order or second order homogenous linear equation? Also, how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: You're almost there. Rearrange to get $dz/z=dx(4-6x)/x^2$ and integrate both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you tried, let $\text{u}\left(x\right)=\text{v}\space'\left(x\right)$:

$$x^2\cdot\text{v}\space''\left(x\right)+\text{v}\space'\left(x\right)\cdot\left(6x-4\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\int\frac{\text{u}\space'\left(x\right)}{\text{u}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=\ln\left|\text{u}\left(x\right)\right|=\int\frac{4-6x}{x^2}\space\text{d}x=-\frac{4}{x}-3\ln\left|36x^2\right|+\text{C}\tag1$$

So, we got:

$$\ln\left|\text{u}\left(x\right)\right|=-\frac{4}{x}-3\ln\left|36x^2\right|+\text{C}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\left|\text{u}\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\text{v}\space'\left(x\right)\right|=\text{C}\cdot\frac{1}{\left|x\right|^6}\cdot\exp\left\{-\frac{4}{x}\right\}\tag2$$